# Why do i get this segdault import numpy error?

Tags: python, numpy

When  I try to import numpy  I get some long error which gives me instructions to try and fix the problem.

I  read it through and tried the solutions but none worked. I just want to import numpy.

```
import numpy
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line , in <module>
ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Solution.py", line 1, in <module>
import numpy
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
22(removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using /usr/local/bin/python3),
and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues. Please include details on:
 how you installed Python
 how you installed numpy
 your operating system
 whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
 if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
```

Original error was: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime"

Also when I run any numpy function I get a segmentation error what does that mean and are there any fixes?

Comment: Update= I tried to use from numpy import array which is the only function I will use instead of importing the whole library but that gave the same long error

Comment: I reinstalled numpy as instructed but didn't fix the problem

Comment: I am not using a git repository and would like to understand this line:

Comment: Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using /usr/local/bin/python3),
and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying. What does this mean?

Comment: Are you using a py distribution like conda?

Comment: i dont know what conda even is so i think not

Comment: Python dependencies i dont even know what that means

Comment: All i did is install the latest version of python and numpy

Comment: nothing more or less

Comment: I am a beginner and was learning a new data type arrays

Comment: It seems like you're just missing a module. Conda is a module manager of sorts. It can make things easier most of the times but other times it can make it impossible. What it does is, it gets all the important modules and puts them together in a distribution. So things like this are less likely to happen. You can try getting that and remove this version of python so it doesn't cause confusion. https://www.anaconda.com/ What OS are you on?

Comment: windows 7 well i kinda get what you mean cuz theres a segmentation error which is calling something out of bounds or something of that sort

Comment: I think conda can work

Comment: ill try and report back

Comment: try to reinstall numpy: first `pip3 uninstall numpy` then `pip3 install numpy`